# Getting multiple line input from console

Tags: java, json

I want to paste a JSON as an input to the console and convert it to string.

```
input:  
{  
    "age":"23",      
    "name":"abc",   
    "blog":"asskakasjsa",  
    "messages":["msg1","msg2","msg3"]   
  }
```

Comment: Which console are you talking about?

Comment: console of eclipse. sorry if i'm saying something foolish of stupid. Consider this question as if i want to get a multi-lined input from user, where the number of lines are not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code reads the line by line input from the user until user enters '}'

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String ip= null;
    try {

        String next;
        do
       {
          next=br.readLine().toString();
           ip+=next;
       }
      while(!next.equalsIgnoreCase("}"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("You have entered:");
    System.out.println(""+ip);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a parsing disaster. You'd probably have to loop `Scanner.nextLine()` and figure out relative positions, parse values, and assign them properly.

I guess you could parse it line by line, make it a big `String`, save it to a .json file, and then use a framework to unmarshal it...?

Generally, this whole concept is not a good idea.

Comment: i'm asking it how to parse it to a string because there is no fixed length of the pasted json.